# ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-01438

Following is my code, I dont understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE COMP_LATE_FEE(LATE_APT_FINE IN NUMBER, LATE_GRG_FINE IN NUMBER)
AS
DIFF NUMBER;
TYPE MBCUR IS REF CURSOR RETURN MONTHLY_BILL%ROWTYPE;
MONBILL MBCUR;
MBREC MONTHLY_BILL%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
--DIFF := FLOOR(SYSDATE - (TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')));
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DIFF);

OPEN MONBILL FOR
    -- checking the status of all last month's bills
    SELECT * FROM MONTHLY_BILL
    WHERE STATUS = 'PENDING' AND SYSDATE > ED_DT;
FETCH MONBILL INTO MBREC;
    -- adding the late fee amount for any bills that are past the due date
    -- due date = last day of the month
    DIFF := FLOOR(ABS(MBREC.ED_DT - (TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'))));
    UPDATE MONTHLY_BILL
    SET LATE_FEE = DIFF * LATE_APT_FINE
    WHERE BILL_NUM = MBREC.BILL_NUM;
    -- if a garage is rented by the resident then the respective additional fee is included
    IF (MBREC.GARAGE_RENT != 0) THEN
        UPDATE MONTHLY_BILL
        SET LATE_FEE = LATE_FEE + DIFF * LATE_GRG_FINE
        WHERE BILL_NUM = MBREC.BILL_NUM;
    END IF;

    COMMIT;
CLOSE MONBILL;
 END;
/
```

The procedure compiled without any err. But I get the following err when i call the proc

```
BEGIN
COMP_LATE_FEE(70,20);
END;
/
```

Error report:

```
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
ORA-06512: at "LALLURI.COMP_LATE_FEE", line 19
ORA-06512: at line 2
01438. 00000 -  "value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"
*Cause:    When inserting or updating records, a numeric value was entered
           that exceeded the precision defined for the column.
*Action:   Enter a value that complies with the numeric column's precision,
           or use the MODIFY option with the ALTER TABLE command to expand
           the precision.
```

Comment: Some intermediate calculation has a greater result than var can store. Perhaps in line: `LATE_FEE = LATE_FEE + DIFF * LATE_GRG_FINE`. Check variable type.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the statement at line 19 is this

```
UPDATE MONTHLY_BILL
SET LATE_FEE = DIFF * LATE_APT_FINE
WHERE BILL_NUM = MBREC.BILL_NUM;
```

the problem would appear to be that the result of the computation `diff * late_apt_fine` is too large for the `late_fee` column in the `monthly_bill` table.  We know that `late_apt_fine` is 70 based on the value of the parameter that was passed in.  Since we don't know the value of the `diff` variable when there is an error and we don't know the definition of the `late_fee` column in `monthly_bill`, it's hard to know whether the problem is that the definition of `late_fee` needs to be changed or whether the computed value is larger than you expect and the algorithm needs to be changed.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Cave. Iunderstand why the problem is arising now. Thank you for taking time to explain.